# How to unshare a shared folder shared to system owner in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, shared-folders

I've shared a folder to myself *(owner of the system in Windows 10)*, but now I cannot unshare it; under *Owner* I don't have *Remove*, etc. How can I do so?

I have tried the following:

- ```
  $ net share c:\users\myuser\desktop\SharedFolder /delete

      Shared resource doesn't exist
  ```

  [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "File sharing" dialog can combine two different things: local sharing using file permissions (ACLs) and network sharing via SMB.

Run `fsmgmt.msc` to see all configured network shares. If I remember correctly, the dialog box creates a single share for the entire C:\Users – not for each individual shared folder.

Use the file's "Properties" window ("Security" tab) to see what custom permissions the folder has.

Comment: Correct: on Desktop, all the C:\Users is unique. On other place, I can remove from there (fsmgmt.msc). Amazing, thanks!